# How may I reset the view of a canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I draw a rectangle in the canvas I know its coordinates, absolute (canvasx(), canvasy()) and relative (the ones that I have passed).
Then, I may be able to move the canvas using the canvas scan_mark() and scan_dragto() methods.
How may I return to the original position (before one or more of these scan_mark()/scan_dragto() calls) in order to re-center the rectangle of which the user might even have lost the position?
Is there any reset view command/method? How may I keep track of the change that has occurred?

Comment: If you know its coordinates of the canvas once it is initially created, couldn't you save those coordinates, and restore those values to the view of the canvas when you want to reset it?

Comment: I know the coordinates of the objects I create, but I do not know how much I have to horizontally and/or vertically scroll the whole canvas to return to the original view. This is the problem I have. Where is this delta stored/available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tkinter documentation I've seen doesn't seem to mention this, but the underlying Tk Canvas xview/yview methods can be called with no parameter to get the current scroll position (actually, as a tuple of two elements, the second not being of any use to you).  So, the following should work (not tested):

Save position:

```
origX = yourcanvas.xview()[0]
origY = yourcanvas.yview()[0]
```

Restore position:

```
yourcanvas.xview_moveto(origX)
yourcanvas.yview_moveto(origY)
```

Comment: Thank you jasonharper. This is exactly what I was looking for. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

As in the previous comment @jasonharper, his suggestion worked. For others who might have the same problem I attach a working example even though it has not been cleaned so well to be proud of, it may give you way to see how zoom in and out, view drag and reset might work.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class GriddedMazeCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def almost_centered(self, cols, rows):

        width = int(self['width'])
        height = int(self['height'])
        cell_dim = self.settings['cell_dim']
        rows = rows % height
        cols = cols % width

        w = cols * cell_dim
        h = rows * cell_dim

        if self.zoom < 0:
            raise ValueError('zoom is negative:', self.zoom)

        zoom = self.zoom // 2 + 1
        if self.drawn() and 1 != zoom:
            w *= zoom
            h *= zoom

        h_shift = (width - w) // 2
        v_shift = (height - h) // 2

        return [h_shift, v_shift,
                h_shift + w, v_shift + h]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'settings' not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("'settings' not passed.")
        settings = kwargs['settings']
        del kwargs['settings']

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.config(highlightthickness=0)

        self.settings = settings
        self.bind_events()

    def draw_maze(self, cols, rows):

        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows

        if self.not_drawn():
            self.cells = {}
            self.cell_dim = self.settings['cell_dim']
            self.border_thickness = self.settings['border_thickness']
            self.zoom = 0

        self.delete(tk.ALL)

        maze, coords = self._draw_maze(cols, rows, fix=False)
        lines = self._draw_grid(coords)

        return maze, lines

    def _draw_maze(self, cols, rows, fix=True):
        data = self.settings

        to_max = data['to_max']
        border_thickness = data['border_thickness']
        poligon_color = data['poligon_color']
        poligon_border_color = data['poligon_border_color']

        coords = self.almost_centered(cols, rows)

        if fix:
            # Fix for the disappearing NW borders
            if to_max == cols:
                coords[0] += 1
            if to_max == rows:
                coords[1] += 1

        maze = self.create_rectangle(*coords,
                                     fill=poligon_color,
                                     outline=poligon_border_color,
                                     width=border_thickness,
                                     tag='maze')
        return maze, coords

    def _draw_grid(self, coords):
        data = self.settings
        poligon_border_color = data['poligon_border_color']
        cell_dim = data['cell_dim']

        if coords is None:
            if self.not_drawn():
                raise ValueError('The maze is still uninitialized.')
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.almost_centered(self.cols, self.rows)
        else:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coords

        if self.drawn() and 0 != self.zoom:
            if self.zoom < 0:
                self.zoom = 0
                print('no zooming at negative values.')
            else:
                zoom = self.zoom // 2 + 1
                cell_dim *= zoom

        lines = []

        for i, x in enumerate(range(x1, x2, cell_dim)):
            line = self.create_line(x, y1, x, y2,
                                    fill=poligon_border_color,
                                    tags=('grid', 'grid_hl_{}'.format(i)))
            lines.append(line)

        for i, y in enumerate(range(y1, y2, cell_dim)):
            line = self.create_line(x1, y, x2, y,
                                    fill=poligon_border_color,
                                    tags=('grid', 'grid_vl_{}'.format(i)))
            lines.append(line)

        return lines

    def drawn(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'cells')

    def not_drawn(self):
        return not self.drawn()

    def bind_events(self):

        self.bind('<Button-4>', self.onZoomIn)
        self.bind('<Button-5>', self.onZoomOut)

        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.onScrollStart)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.onScrollMove)
        self.tag_bind('maze', '<ButtonPress-3>', self.onMouseRight)

    def onScrollStart(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y, self.canvasx(event.x), self.canvasy(event.y))
        self.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

    def onMouseRight(self, event):
        col, row = self.get_pos(event)
        print('zoom, col, row:', self.zoom, col, row)

    def onScrollMove(self, event):
        delta = event.x, event.y
        self.scan_dragto(*delta, gain=1)

    def onZoomIn(self, event):
        if self.not_drawn():
            return

        max_zoom = 16

        self.zoom += 2
        if self.zoom > max_zoom:
            print("Can't go beyond", max_zoom)
            self.zoom = max_zoom
            return

        print('Zooming in.', event.num, event.x, event.y, self.zoom)
        self.draw_maze(self.cols, self.rows)

    def onZoomOut(self, event):
        if self.not_drawn():
            return

        self.zoom -= 2
        if self.zoom < 0:
            print("Can't go below zero.")
            self.zoom = 0
            return

        print('Zooming out.', event.num, event.x, event.y, self.zoom)
        self.draw_maze(self.cols, self.rows)

    def get_pos(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        cols, rows = self.cols, self.rows
        cell_dim, zoom = self.cell_dim, self.zoom
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.almost_centered(cols, rows)

        if not (x1 <= x <= x2 and y1 <= y <= y2):
            print('Here we are out of bounds.')
            return None, None

        scale = (zoom // 2 + 1) * cell_dim

        col = (x - x1) // scale
        row = (y - y1) // scale

        return col, row


class CanvasButton(ttk.Button):

    def freeze_origin(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'origin'):
            canvas = self.canvas
            self.origin = canvas.xview()[0], canvas.yview()[0]

    def reset(self):
        canvas = self.canvas
        x, y = self.origin
        canvas.yview_moveto(x)
        canvas.xview_moveto(y)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not 'canvas' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("'canvas' not passed.")
        canvas = kwargs['canvas']
        del kwargs['canvas']

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.config(command=self.reset)

        self.canvas = canvas


root = tk.Tk()

settings = {'cell_dim': 3,
            'to_max': 200,
            'border_thickness': 1,
            'poligon_color': '#F7F37E',
            'poligon_border_color': '#AC5D33'}

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = GriddedMazeCanvas(frame,
                           settings=settings,
                           width=640,
                           height=480)
button = CanvasButton(frame, text='Reset', canvas=canvas)
button.freeze_origin()

canvas.draw_maze(20, 10)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Tested with Python 3.4 on latest Ubuntu 16.10
(Events: MouseLeft, Mouseright, MouseWheel, ButtonPress)
HTH